# PostgreSQL 9.3 long running queries

Tags: sql, postgresql, locking, database-administration

```
 select vesseltrav0_.id as id1_0_, vesseltrav0_.created as created2_0_, vesseltrav0_.lastUpdated as lastUpda3_0_, vesseltrav0_.geoFenceId as geoFence4_0_, 
        vesseltrav0_.geoFenceName as geoFence5_0_, vesseltrav0_.mmsi as mmsi6_0_, vesseltrav0_.position as position7_0_, vesseltrav0_.timestamp as timestam8_0_, 
        vesseltrav0_.vesselEnteredTime as vesselEn9_0_, vesseltrav0_.vesselExitTime as vesselE10_0_, vesseltrav0_.vesselId as vesselI11_0_ 
 from VESSEL_ENTERED_GEOFENCE vesseltrav0_ where vesseltrav0_.geoFenceId=$1 and vesseltrav0_.vesselId=$2
```

I have a daemon logging records to the database and updating them periodically but it seems once or twice an hour this fairly innocent looking SQL will just refuse to finish.

```
CREATE TABLE public.vessel_entered_geofence
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  geofenceid character varying(36),
  geofencename character varying(128),
  mmsi character varying(32),
  vesselenteredtime timestamp without time zone,
  vesselexittime timestamp without time zone,
  vesselid character varying(36),
  created timestamp without time zone,
  lastupdated timestamp without time zone,
  "position" geometry(Point,4326),
  "timestamp" timestamp without time zone,
  CONSTRAINT vessel_entered_geofence_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX vessel_entered_geofence_idx
  ON public.vessel_entered_geofence
  USING btree
  (mmsi COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX vessel_entered_geofence_gid_idx
ON public.vessel_entered_geofence
USING btree
(geofenceid COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX vessel_entered_geofence_vid_idx
ON public.vessel_entered_geofence
USING btree
(vesselid COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

When I run the explain plan on the SQL it is using the index and manually running the SQL returns an answer very quickly. All of the connections have a state of idle (edit: they are all "idle in transaction") and they're not waiting for anything (according to pg_stats_activity).

```
select * from pg_stat_activity order by backend_start
```

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pp8X.png

```
select a.*, b.relname from pg_locks a left outer join pg_class b on a.relation = b.oid
```

[image]
https://puu.sh/gGE9n/96da69d341.png

I'm not really sure where to look next to determine what the problem is, they seem to be idle, not waiting for anything and there are no locks on the table that should cause them to hang (unless I'm reading it wrong). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: the daemon is running select you provided at the top?..

Comment: Thats the query text returned by pg_stat_activity.query. But yeah this is called from the Java Daemon originally

Comment: oh jaaaaavaaaa... I see now. I had same with java not terminating connection after completion. We did not solve it - just created a job to terminate java if it completed execution and did not exit :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I've solved this finally. It was a missing a begin/commit in the Java code.

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
//perform query
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Even if the query only contains a select statement, it will hang if you don't encapsulate it in a transaction.